# How to post to an image to friend's wall without resize it?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook-c#-sdk

using OAuth/Facebook-C#-SDK? when I post an image like:

http://im.in.com/connect/images/profile/oct2009/Google_300.jpg

is resized to:

[image]

my C# code:

```
var args = new Dictionary<string, string>();
args["message"] = "..."; 
args["picture"] = "http://im.in.com/connect/images/profile/oct2009/Google_300.jpg";
string uri = String.Format("{0}/feed", id);
dynamic result = facebook.Post(uri, args);
```

how to fix this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no "fixing" this. Facebook shrinks images to fit their image size limits for feed posts.